# nginx : differentiate urls with rewrite rules

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to differentiate urls, the structure is like this :

```
http://domain/category 1/
             /category n/
             /region 1/
             /region n/
             /city 1/
             /city n/
```

the number of different possibilities is minimum 40k, I wondered how to know if the parameter in the url chosen is a city, a region or a category?

Any idea ?
or maybe to get this parameter with a rewrite rule and then to make tests with queries in the database? what is better? how many rewrite rules nginx can support ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want something along the lines of:

```
rewrite ^/(\w+)\%20(\d+)/$ index.php?category=$1&id=$2 last;
```

This should rewrite the URL as get parameters on a PHP script. It should be much easier to maintain than 40K of rules.

(note the above is untested, off the top of my head)